# Is there a way to filter which columns are visible in PowerBI visual?

Tags: powerbi, dax, slicers

Question: how can I use PowerBI's features to help me "filter out" which columns I'd like to see in my visual?

For example, observe the columns below (the ones in blue are measures, whereas the others are simply columns). I'd like to be able to filter out "Ferrari" data and "Porsche" columns separately; that is, there'd be a "Ferrari" option in the slicer to allow me to see columns 2-4, and another option (i.e., "Porsche") in the slicer would allow me to see columns 5-7.

[image]

Thank you in advance!

If anyone would like a workable example, you can [click here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1RZZrnGybUZAb0Ge8shCOwX8RfrsTFSZV5YnQpTeI1Xw/edit?usp=sharing) to see the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to approach this would be to unpivot your data & add a column to distinguish between Ferrari and Porsche.

i.e. Instead of:

[image: Unpivoted]

Do this:

[image: Pivoted]

Notice the extra column to distinguish between Ferrari and Porsche. That extra column is what you'd then use on your slicer:

[image: Final result]

By unpivoting, this problem becomes easy to solve whereas working with pivoted data will always lead to very complicated DAX expressions. (Not saying that this can't be solved in DAX, but I don't recommend trying.)

*Also, note that unpivoting can be performed in the Query Editor as you load your data into Power BI. It's not something you have to do your source data outside Power BI (unless you want to).*

Comment: Thank you, @Leonard. Just to confirm (I'm still new to this), am I "pivoting" on the "Race ID" column?

Comment: It's a little more complicated than that admittedly. The steps I took were to highlight the Race ID column and then "unpivot other columns". That creates a column called Attribute with your column names as values. However, it unpivots everything. Then, I added a new conditional column for the car type to say if "Attribute" begins with F then Ferrari, otherwise Porsche. After that, a custom column to remove the car prefixes from the Attribute column (so Porsche Miles becomes Miles): Text.Range([Attribute], 7). Finally, I highlighted this final new column & the "Value" column and pivoted them.

Comment: It's definitely easier if it can come from your source system already unpivoted.